# How to properly set the visibility property in CMake with gcc?

Tags: gcc, cmake

I tried a couple of options to properly set the visibility in my library. Like:

```
target_compile_options(MY_LIB PRIVATE "-fvisibility=hidden")
set_target_properties(MY_LIB PROPERTIES C_VISIBILITY_PRESET hidden VISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN 1)
set_target_properties(MY_LIB PROPERTIES CXX_VISIBILITY_PRESET hidden VISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN 1)
```

or

```
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -fvisibility=hidden")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fvisibility=hidden")
```

And both don't work. I have the specific functions that I want to expose set inside a block

```
#pragma GCC visibilty push(default)
  void thisShouldBeTheOnlyThingVisible(void) {
    ...
  }
#pragma GCC visibilty pop
```

But, if I run different tools, like *objdump* or *readelf*, not only I'm seeing all the internal functions that should not be listed, I also see file names and non static variable names. I wouldn't mind in *debug* mode, but in *release*, it shouldn't be there.

What's the right process here to get everything that I want hidden except those special functions?

Thanks

W

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for:

```
add_library(MY_LIB ${MY_SOURCES})
set_property(TARGET MY_LIB PROPERTY C_VISIBILITY_PRESET hidden)
set_property(TARGET MY_LIB PROPERTY VISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN ON)
```

At least, as of cmake 3.14.4.

Determined this by looking at CMake's test:

https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Tests/Visibility/CMakeLists.txt